# How to map(profile) function calls in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, profiler

I'm trying to get the order of script and function calls in a flask app. This application gets the data, pre-processes it and clusters and finally returns the clustering result to the user. I'm trying to get a map of the whole procedure. I mean, I need to get the 'history' of a single run. I've tried to use cProfiler in PyCharm Pro but I didn't understand a single information came from there. I need something like: 'def read_data > def preprocess_data > def cluster_data > def return_data'.

PS: I know this is not a good explanation and there is a 'name' for what I'm looking for but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You're trying to get the call stack at a given point?

Comment: You are looking for the call stack. To see it, you can just create a brakepoint in PyCharm (any Edition), run your program in "debug" mode (green bug icon), wait for it to reach the brakepoint and then you can inspect the call stack in the debug view (bottom left on default PyCharm).

Comment: Yup. You are right. I was looking for 'call stack'. And as @Frieder said I can get it in debug mode. And there are possible duplicates all over the stackoverflow. Thank you all.